# Controlling AVR reset via voltage divider

Tags: avr, reset, usbasp

I have an AVR atmega32u4 which is being run on 3.3v. I program it using a avr usbisp, which runs at 5v.. The problem i'm having is driving the reset pin.. I currently have this schematic where PROG_RESET is the 5V/GND reset pin on the programmer, and AVR_RESET goes to the AVR IC's reset pin...[image]

What I am seeing is: programming works brilliantly, but the chip never boots, as AVR_RESET is constantly held at ~100mV - low enough for the IC to stay in reset. Even when only connecting power. Briding the 10K resistor doesn't seem to boot it either.. What values of resistors should I change to, to make the reset divider functional?

Comment: Excuse me, but if the target is running at 3.3V and programmer at 5V, how have you solved that issue to begin with for the other programming pins? Wouldn't the same apply to the reset pin too?

Comment: @Justme the atmega32u4 is capable of running at 5V aswell, so it has no problems programming from a 5V SPI, even when running at 3.3V itself.

Comment: That is simply not true. If the MCU runs at 3.3V, and the programming interface uses 5V, the programmer tries to drive 5V on the 3.3V MCU pins and the 3.3V protection diodes try to clamp the voltage and current flows via protection diodes to 3.3V, and if it is very lightly loaded, the supply voltage may get pushed up to around 4.5V.

Comment: fwiw, I believe the reset pin on AVR chips is different from the other pins and allows V>Vdd , as a special signal to enter an alternate programming mode [(reference)](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/How-to-perform-High-Voltage-Programming-on-AVR-devices) ... this is different from the more common serial programming

Comment: @PeteW Exactly, the reset pin on AVR is the only one that allows higher voltages than the supplied VDD, because it is used for going into HV programming mode. The other pins do not allow this. And this is exactly about in-system serial programming of a 3.3V target with a 5V USBISP programmer, which is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a resistor in this way will not work. The 10k resistor and 310 resistor form a potential divider which means that when `PROG_RESET` is floating, there will be \$V=\frac{3.3\times310}{10k+310}=0.1V\$ at the reset pin.

Instead you should use a level shifting circuit which either drives the `RESET` line high when the programmer is not connected, or has a high-impedance output.

If you want a simple modification to your existing circuit, you could replace your two low-value resistors with an N-channel MOSFET, using the following circuit:

[image: Simple MOSFET Level Shifter]

The MOSFET could also be replaced by a diode with Anode to AVR_RESET, and Cathode to PROG_RESET. In this case, it should be a schottky type diode with a low forward voltage drop (maybe < 0.5V) to ensure the AVR reliably detects a logic 0.

Comment: would just a diode be sufficient?

Comment: @PeteW Fair point. Diode should work too as long as it's forward voltage drop is low enough to allow the reset pin to detect a logic 0

Comment: Thank you! I will try the diode... This is what happens when you design parts of boards late at night for a deadline the next morning...

Comment: @RandoHinn watch out for other issues as well - Like the 5V programmer being capable of pushing the 3.3V of your board up to about 4.5V, something might break.

Comment: @Justme and Rando -- diode pointing away from reset pin